# manipulating/reading before passing to command

Tags: go, command, buffer

How to read/manipulate the input from a connection that is passed to a command stdin?

For example, given the following code.

```
    c, _ := net.Dial("tcp", somehost)
    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh")
    cmd.Stdin, cmd.Stdout, cmd.Stderr = c, c, c
    cmd.Run()
```

How would it be possible to reverse the string from the connection before it is passed to the cmd.Stdin or how could I parse the string and not pass it on to cmd.Stdin?

Ive considered reading from the connection with bufio and then passing it to Command second argument, the params, but I was hoping for a better solution that does not require me to handle all the different cases for args input in a command, but instead just passing it on to Stdin after analysing the input

Comment: I guess you will need a protocol when you read bytes into string. Like when you receive a  word reverse it. But how you detect end of word so that you can do reverse and redirect it to stdout? You can send length of word as first 2 bytes then Read those many bytes reverse, redirect. Repeat.

Comment: Okay, my real issue is how to intercept the input from the connection, parse it and parse it to the Stdin of the command. Seems when I do cmd.Run() I block and hence cant really continously parse. I think it might be solvable with io.pipe and or io.copy but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: You need to parse and redirect to stdin concurrently. Check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok since you mentioned in comments that *"my real issue is how to intercept the input from the connection, parse it and parse it to the Stdin of the command. Seems when I do cmd.Run() I block and hence cant really continously parse"*

Here is how I will do it:

```
import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    //All errors are not checked
    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh")
    cmdStdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    go func() {
        defer cmdStdin.Close()
        //here you will need to loop on reading the connection, 
        //for simplicity lets assume you do that & receive data
        //let says you got ls from connection
        cmdStdin.Write([]byte("ls\n"))
    }()
    cmdStdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, cmdStdout)
    cmd.Run()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I was using a method of `bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')`  checking the string, and creating a new Reader from the string passing the to the cmd.stdIn and using cmd.Output to execute (so I had a loop to manage it)